# Prevent file access from actual url and use rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

i have a situation here for htaccess. I'm fairly new to htaccess. 
So, am using codeigniter. Now i wanna do a redirect.

The origional url for codeigniter is:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/getz
```

Now, i wanna have user type www.mysite.com/agetz to access the above url. fairly fine till now. It does it by:

```
RewriteRule ^agetz$ /index.php/admin/getz [L]
```

Now, what i wanna do is that when people type the real url i.e. www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/getz, i want to redirect them to 404 page(secure the url from others for some security reasons), and when they type www.mysite.com/agetz, i want to allow them the accesss to getz controller.

Problem is that currently if i do any trick to kick anyone typing url www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/agetz to 404, it also kicks mysite.com/getz. Have to do it with .htaccess.

Comment: I guess you can use sessions ($_SESSION[]) to authenticate the request going to www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/agetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your existing code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php/admin/getz/?[\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^agetz/?$ /index.php/admin/getz [L,NC]
```